# How do I draw part of the sprite image using pygame spritegroups?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, draw

I want to draw a part of the sprite image to slowly reveal it.  If I was handling the draw I would just do:

```
def draw(self, screen):
    screen.blit(self.image, self.rect, self.viewport)
```

and change the viewport size in the objects update method. I tried adding this to the code but it just shows the whole image.  The update is definitely being called by the spritegroup update method and the viewport rect is being updated correctly, and in the game draw I have:

```
self.all_sprites.draw(screen)
```

How would I achieve this using pygame spritegroups? Also, none of the sprites have a draw method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a subsurface that is directly linked to the source surface with the method [`subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface):

> `subsurface(Rect) -> Surface`
>
> Returns a new Surface that shares its pixels with its new parent. The new Surface is considered a child of the original. Modifications to either Surface pixels will effect each other.

Create the *subsurface* either once in the constructor or continuously in an `update` method. e.g.:

```py
class SpriteObject(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image):
        # [...]

        self.complete_image = image 
        
    def update(self):
        self.image = self.complete_image.subsurface(self.viewport)
```

Now you don't need the `draw` method anymore and can use `self.all_sprites.draw(screen)`, because the `image` attribute is a subsurface of the entire image. [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects.

Comment: Wow, thanks again. It is working but the wrong way round loll, but I am pretty sure I can fix that.  I saw your collision and mask stuff on here yesterday, that is some quality stuff.  This is for my shoot em up which I am slowly completing.  It is a bit different to that invaders thing from the other day lol.

Comment: Got it working! looks mint, thanks again!